# Vue error makes no sense: Unhandled error during execution of scheduler flush. onVnodeUnmounted=fn<onVnodeUnmounted> ref=Ref< null > >

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, vue-router, vuejs3

I think this problem stems from a parent template having multiple children in `Vue.js 3` with `Vue Router 4`. I never had this problem in prior version of both packages.

I have a simple `App.vue` file:

```
<template>
    <div id="app">
         <main id="content">
                    <div id="nav">
                        <!--<router-link to="/about">About</router-link>-->
                        <router-link to="/information">Information</router-link>
                        <router-link :to="{ path: '/create', name: 'PostCreate'}">Create</router-link>
                    </div>
                    <router-view></router-view>
         </main>
</template>
```

The `router-link to="/information"` link works fine. It just loads the view which has no other components inside it.

The other `router-link :to="{ path: '/create', name: 'PostCreate'}"` fails after repeatedly trying to load the component about 50 times and logs this in the console:

```
 [Vue warn]: Unhandled error during execution of scheduler flush. This is likely a Vue internals bug. Please open an issue at https://new-issue.vuejs.org/?repo=vuejs/vue-next 
  at <PostCreate> 
  at <PostCreate>  
  at <PostCreate>  
  ... // repeats over and over again until
  at <PostCreate onVnodeUnmounted=fn<onVnodeUnmounted> ref=Ref< null > > 
  at <RouterView> 
  at <App> 
  at <App>
```

**vuerouter.js**

```
const routes = [
    {
        path: '/',
        name: 'HomeView',
        component: HomeView
    },
    {
        path: '/information',
        name: 'Information',
        component: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "Information" */ '../views/information/Information.vue')
    }
    ,
    {
        path: '/create',
        name: 'PostCreate',
        component: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "Create" */ '../views/posts/PostCreate.vue')
    }
];
```

The only difference between `Information.vue` and `PostCreate.vue` is that the latter imports another `vue` component to make a `form` for the user to create a post.

**Information.vue**

```
<template>
<div>
<p>I am full of good info</p>
</div>
</template>
<script>
    export default {
        name: 'Information'
    }
</script>
```

**PostCreate.vue**

```
<template>
    <div class="content">

            <h1>I make a form</h1>
            <Post-Create></Post-Create>

    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import PostCreate from "../../components/PostCreate.vue";

    export default {
        name: "PostCreate",
        components: {
            "Post-Create": PostCreate
        }
    }
</script>
```

Why is this an issue in Vue.js 3 with Vue-Router 4 whereas it worked fine previously? How do I solve it?

Comment: According to the error, "`this is a Vue internals bug.`". You should open a new issue at the given URL(IMHO)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This happens because the `PostCreate` view is trying to recursively load itself.  Since you used the same name for the view and the child component, the parent name overwrites the child name in the registration, and the view tries to load itself instead of the child.

It's the equivalent of this, which would also lead to the view trying to load itself.

```html
<template>
  <div class="content">
    <h1>I make a form</h1>
    <PostCreate></PostCreate>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "PostCreate",
};
</script>
```

<sup>You won't get a `Failed to resolve component` error, because it takes `<PostCreate></PostCreate>` to be itself.  You get that same recursion error instead.</sup>

So you just need to rename the child component.  It's a good practice to always use different filenames too, for different components, especially in larger projects, to keep files clear.

Comment: Thank you shob. Is this mentioned anywhere in the docs? And is this usually how vague debugging is going to be in Vue? Is there a better way of debugging

Comment: @volumeone You're welcome.  I don't think I've ever seen it explicitly mentioned in the naming [docs](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-registration.html).  It is a little unintuitive too, you're right, but I think it's a fairly rare case and debugging is usually more straightforward